# CodeIgniter URL: web.com/user/register/step/1

Tags: codeigniter, url, parameters

I have controller "user" and function "register" but I want to make 3 steps in register, how to make this for example **www.web.com/user/register/step/1**?

Comment: Your question unclear. You might need to look here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function user()
{
    if ($this->uri->segment(2) !== 'register' || $this->uri->segment(3) !== 'step' || (int)$this->uri->segment(4) < 1)
    {
        redirect('user/register/step/1', 'refresh');
    }

    switch($this->uri->segment(4)) {
        case 1:
            $this->step1();
            break;
        case 2:
            $this->step2();
            break;
        case 3:
            $this->step3();
            break;
        default:
            redirect('user/register/step/1', 'refresh');
    }
}

private function step1()
{
    //code for step 1
    redirect('user/register/step/2', 'refresh');
}

private function step2()
{
    //code for step 2
    redirect('user/register/step/3', 'refresh');
}

private function step3()
{
    //code for step 3
    redirect('where-ever-after-registration', 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a jQuery step wise form plugin. Checkout this link http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples